# Put text on an arrow

Tags: formatting, arrows

I am trying to put some text over an arrow using:

```
\longmapsto{p},
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this one?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}        
    $\xmapsto{P}$
\end{document}
```